# Looking for a system: Epidemic Outbreak

Tags: game-recommendation, disease, horror

What system could suit a short-term survival-horror campaign focused on a "realistic" epidemic outbreak scenario? (Realistic as in crunchy or gritty-ish, I know it's pretty vague, sorry)
I'm thinking about a quarantine setting, with the PC's needing to adjust themselves to the situation (both psychologically and physically). Hunger and thirsty, crimes, state repression and (of course) the disease itself. (No zombies, please :p)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry this question isn't on-topic for mainsite; our [curated list of forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/23970) might help, as might Our Very Own [chat].